# VBA - split cell value by font colour

Tags: vba, excel

I've been given a spreadsheet with a range of cells, each of which contains a list of numbers.

Each number has been given a font colour, so in one cell you might have two orange numbers, a red one and a green one. I need to treat each colour differently; for example, I can count green and red numbers as they are, but I need to see if each orange number occurs in previous cells in the range before counting it.

The number lists are comma-separated, so getting individual numbers shouldn't be a problem, but how do you retain and work with the colour information?

I'd post code, but frankly I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some more info on "but I need to see if each orange number occurs in previous cells in the range before counting it." please......

Comment: Several numbers in each cell ? Could you maybe insert a screenshot, that'd be very helpful.

Comment: Try recording a macro where you simply "select" a colored number. This will be the foundation of your code. Post that here and then describe in a little more detail what you are attempting to *do*, otherwise, it's going to be difficult to assist you at all.

Comment: Check `Range.Characters.Font.Color`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses all.  I eventually cracked it with something similar to this thread:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/656265-excel-visual-basic-applications-count-items-cell-color-font.html

Basically it's a loop that looks at the colour of the character after each comma.  I've just modified it so that if the ColorIndex = 46, it copies the characters before the next comma into an array

Answer (score 1):

Solved using this:

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/656265-excel-visual-basic-applications-count-items-cell-color-font.html

Essentially a loop that uses InStr to find commas in a string (in this case, the contents of a cell), then looks at the colour of the next character after the comma.  I've just edited it to say if the ColorIndex = 46, copy the subsequent characters into a space in an array.  Then I can look at each item in the array, and compare it with other cells in the range to see if it appears elsewhere.