# Extracting font color from cells with multiple colors in the cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet that I am trying to get into a MySQL database.

- I am using VBA to write the data out as text into a file and then upload that to the database.
- In the cells of the worksheet there are strings which have been color coded.
- The colors have a certain meaning so I want to preserve them when I move the values into the database (I have a special column in the database where I enumerate the colors).

The thing is that some cells have strings separated by commas and on one side of the comma the string is black, on the other side it is blue (or vice versa and there can be more commas and strings in the cell).

*what I have tried*

I can extract the strings fine by using the `Split` function in VBA but that loses the formatting of the string.

I can get the color of a cell using `Range("mycell").Font.ColorIndex` but that returns `NULL` if there is more then one color in the string.

Is it possible to get all the colors of a string?

Example: one cell could contain the following string

> "W345, PO3244, 12309"
>    1.  (W345) would be black (colorindex -4105),
>    2.  (PO3244) would be blue (colorindex 47)
>    3.  (12309) would be red (colorindex 3).

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509806/vba-split-cell-value-by-font-colour

Comment: Thanks katz, I will try the solution there. Surprised I didn't find that question myself, my google foo is usually better then this. Thanks also pnuts for the kind words, my question asking foo is not always this good though as can be seen from other questions on other stackexchange sites. But one tries to improve.

Comment: you might be interested in this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32713544/advanced-text-editing-for-vba-excel-textbox?noredirect=1#comment53272537_32713544

Comment: David Zemens has an interesting post on XML in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117667/how-to-read-xml-attributes-using-vba-to-excel/19118292#comment53326811_19118292  Look a promising approach (that will need further setup) but liley more workable than a huge iterative process character by character, cell by cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `.Font.Color` to cull the RGB values, but you can change it to ColorIndex if you like.

You can adapt this strategy:

```
Sub CellColors2CSV()
    Dim j&, k&, c$, r As Range
    Set r = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1)
    Do
        j = Len(r)
        k = InStr(k + 1, r, ",")
        If k Then j = k - 1
        c = c & "," & r.Characters(j, 1).Font.Color
    Loop Until k = 0
    c = Mid$(c, 2)
    MsgBox c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, yes, that got me on the right track. I submit my own answer with my adapted solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following and then create a dictionary/collection/array to store the colors and only keep unique values or whatever solution fits your situation. This just shows how you can access all the colors.

```
Sub AllColors()

Dim r As Range
Dim x As Integer

Set r = Selection

For x = 1 To Len(r.Value)
    Debug.Print r.Characters(x, 1).Font.ColorIndex
Next x


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

After the answer from Excel Hero then I managed to concoct up this code which fulfilled my needs which are a function that returns the colors in a Collection (could be an array also):

```
Function GetColors(i, j) As Collection
Dim l&, k&, r As Range
Dim c As Collection
Set c = New Collection
Set r = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)
Do
    l = Len(r)
    If Not InStr(r, ",") Then
        k = InStr(k + 1, r, ",")
    ElseIf Not InStr(r, " / ") Then
        k = InStr(k + 1, r, " / ")
    End If
    If k Then l = k - 1
    c.Add r.Characters(l, 1).Font.ColorIndex
Loop Until k = 0
Set GetColors = c
End Function
```