# Splitting Excel cell string while keeping font color formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have posted this question before but it was voted as too vague. So here I am trying again.

I have a cell with letters with different colors. Each letter is evenly spaced with one another (See below). I need to split them into separate cells with their color formatting intact using VBA.

The actual font colors are expressed in `[]` brackets

I need to split:

```
  |A                              |
1 |Alan[Red] Betty[Blue] Cass[Red]|
```

Into:

```
  |A           |
1 |Alan[Red]   |
2 |Betty[Blue] |
3 |Cass[Red]   |
```

I was only able to extract values in the original string but not the individual letter's formatting.

I've tried `Text to Columns` as well but all the split cells are not formatted. Even manual copy pasting does not work when only selecting partial string in the cell.

How can I accomplish splitting the string while keeping the color via VBA?

The code I used is part of a larger chunk of other things but the simplified logic is this:

```
Sub test()
Dim strLength As Long
Dim breakPos As Long
Dim spaceCount As Long

strLength = Len(Cells(1, 1))
spaceCount = strLength - Len(Replace(Cells(1, 1), " ", ""))

For i = 1 To spaceCount
    strLength = Len(Cells(i, 1))
    breakPos = InStr(1, Cells(i, 1), " ")
    Cells(i + 1, 1) = Right(Cells(i, 1), strLength - breakPos)
    Cells(i, 1) = Left(Cells(i, 1), breakPos - 1)
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What code have you tried? Please include it in your question and explain where you ran into trouble.

Comment: @braX I've edited the post with a simplified version of the code. Hope it helps.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32741136/extracting-font-color-from-cells-with-multiple-colors-in-the-cell

Comment: You will need to loop over the `Characters` collection to look for changes in the color of each letter, then split the string where it changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to result in what you describe.

- Split the cell into words
- Write the words to the new location
- Check the font of the original word and set that color to the new location

In your "production" code, you'll want to more strongly declare the workbook and worksheet, and you will probably be doing this on more than a single cell, so you'll probably need to add some loops and statements to adjust for different ranges than just A1 and A3 as you show in your question.

```
Option Explicit
Sub splitWithColor()
    Dim vStr As Variant, v
    Dim rSrc As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

'Note we are working with "active sheet"
'you should have stronger definitions in final product
Set rSrc = Range("A1")
Set rRes = Range("A3")

vStr = Split(rSrc.Value2)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vStr) + 1)
rRes.Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vStr)
I = 0
J = 1
For Each v In vStr
    rRes.Offset(I)(1).Font.Color = rSrc.Characters(J, 1).Font.Color
    I = I + 1
    J = J + Len(v) + 1
Next v

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Modified it slightly so as to remove words that have a strikethrough

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, please. Al words in the analyzed string must have **the same font color for all their characters**, they **must be separated by spaces (" ")**. The result will be returned below the processed cell. In this example, below of active cell. If necessary, it can replace the selected cell, of course, but you cannot repeat the test for the same cell...

```
Sub splitByWordsKeepingFontColor()
  Dim c As Range, i As Long, arrRes As Variant, arrCol() As Variant
    Set c = ActiveCell: If c.Text = "" Then MsgBox "Emply cell selection...": Exit Sub
    arrRes = Split(c.Text, " ")
    If UBound(arrRes) = 0 Then MsgBox "No strings separated by space ("" "") exist in """ & _
                                                               c.Text & """.": Exit Sub
    ReDim arrCol(UBound(arrRes))
      For i = 0 To UBound(arrRes)
        arrCol(i) = c.Characters(InStr(c.Text, arrRes(i)), _
                                                    Len(arrRes(i))).Font.ColorIndex
      Next i
      c.Offset(1, 0).Resize(UBound(arrRes) + 1, 1) = _
                                    Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrRes)
      For i = 0 To UBound(arrCol)
        c.Offset(i + 1, 0).Font.ColorIndex = arrCol(i)
      Next i      
End Sub
```